# Ionic cordova - QRcode generate example

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, qr-code

I'm building a cordova application using ionic framework. This application need the ability to generate a QRcode based on the given text. I found http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ as a solution. But I could not implement this in my ionic application. I need some example for this task, implemented by qrcodejs, or any other libraries.Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Neither [angular-qr](https://github.com/janantala/angular-qr) nor [angular-qrcode](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode) worked for me, so I ended up rolling my own directive real quick, based on [Shim Sangmin's QRCode generator library](http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/):

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script src="lib/qrcode.js/qrcode.js"></script>
```

-

```
// directives.js
.directive('qrcode', function($interpolate) {  
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

      var options = {
        text: '',
        width: 128,
        height: 128,
        colorDark: '#000000',
        colorLight: '#ffffff',
        correctLevel: 'H'
      };

      Object.keys(options).forEach(function(key) {
        options[key] = $interpolate($attrs[key] || '')($scope) || options[key];
      });

      options.correctLevel = QRCode.CorrectLevel[options.correctLevel];

      new QRCode($element[0], options);

    }
  };
});
```

Then use it like so:

```
<qrcode text="{{something.on.scope}}" color-bright="#ff0000"></qrcode>
<!-- or width, height, color-dark, correct-level -->
```

Edit: Check it out on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miffels/81pggmq0/2/).

Comment: @Chandru Care to elaborate? Are there any specific errors?

Comment: @Chandru I just rebuilt my project from scratch using [qrcode.js 04f46c6a07](https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/tree/04f46c6a0708418cb7b96fc563eacae0fbf77674) pulled into the project via bower. Still working.

Comment: it was not showing any error. it was not showing the qrcode either. Howerver, I managed to make angular-qrcode working. I was just missing 'monospaced.qrcode' in dependency list.

Comment: @Chandru Well, unfortunately that is not very useful in making sure others won't run into trouble. Please check out [my example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miffels/81pggmq0/2/) and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I agree your concern.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is a angular module, most the time you would have to create your own directive, module, or angular code to integrate a JavaScript plug-in. But someone has already done that, I would take a look at http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-qr should be what you are looking for. 
See the demo: http://janantala.github.io/angular-qr/demo/

Answer (score 0):

I finally made angular-qrcode working. The issue was that, I am supposed to include 'monospaced.qrcode' as a module dependency in app.js. This was missing in my case.

Comment: Please add a little detail how you fixed it and which plugin you used